# No identifier specified for entity Exception in springJpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

While running springboot application,  exception is coming.

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.model.Location

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@Table(name = "LOCATION", schema = "LOCK")
public class Location implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "LOCATION_ID")
    private int locationId;
    @Column(name = "LOCATION", nullable = false)
    private String location;


    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp CREATED_ON;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_ON", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp UPDATED_ON;

    /*getter setter methods*/
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me.. can you @Access(value=AccessType.FIELD). to the class definition?

Comment: Still getting the same issue..

Comment: Can u confirm if you are importing  javax.persistence.Id in this class

Comment: Thanks shubham, I imported @Id from wrong package (org.springframework). Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the identifier is loaded from the package:

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

and no

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
```